# Select2 displaying undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin, the plugin is working fine, except when I use javascript to populate options it displays 'undefined'. I want it to display 'Select Type', I am not able to add selected to the 'Select Type' option as this is not possible because this is created by javascript.

This is what my code looks like before calling javascript:

```
<select name="ivprodtype" size="1" class="span3 no-margin-bottom"></select>
```

This is what it looks like after calling  javascript:

```
<select name="ivprodtype" size="1" class="span3 no-margin-bottom">
 <option value="">Select Type</option>
 <option value="accessories">Accessories</option>
 <option value="bags">Bags</option>
 <option value="bbq">Barbecue</option> /*followed by many other options*/
</select>
```

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: Have you included  ,Select2.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script..

```
<script>
function f(){
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Select Type',
    ValueB : 'Accessories',
    ValueC : 'Bags'
    ValueD : 'Barbecue'
};

var select = document.getElementById("id");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, the options in coming from CMS so I can't really make changes to them, I am trying to use place holder configuration (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: Hi guys, I sorted this out, I used jQuery to remove the value attribute that have empty value from the targeted option after it is been called from the VCP and it is working fine, I think select2 doesn't like empty value attributes.